# Error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ when attempting to pass arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, int

I am in a C++ class, and for a project we need to calculate grades using arrays, and at least 3 functions outside of main. 
My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double gradeAverage(double, double, double, double);
double letterGrade(double);
double arrayAverage(int, int);
void droppedQuizzes(int, int);


int main(){
    int quizGrades[7] = {100, 0, 50, 30, 40, 100, 0};
    int testGrades[2] = {50, 54};
    int projectGrades[4] = {100, 0, 90, 95};
    int labGrades[6] = {100, 100, 0, 50, 60, 100};
    int newQuizGrades[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};



    droppedQuizzes(quizGrades, newQuizGrades);


    double quizAve = arrayAverage(quizGrades, 7);
    double testAve = arrayAverage(testGrades, 2);
    double projAve = arrayAverage(projectGrades, 4);
    double labAve = arrayAverage(labGrades, 6);

    double gradeAve = gradeAverage(quizAve, testAve, projAve, labAve);

    char finalGrade = letterGrade (gradeAve);

    cout << "Final Numeric Average: " << gradeAve << endl << "Letter Grade: " << finalGrade << endl;

    return 0;
}

double gradeAverage(double quiz, double test, double proj, double lab){
    double quizWeighted = quiz * 0.2;
    double testWeighted = test * 0.25;
    double projWeighted = proj * 0.2;
    double labWeighted = lab * 0.15;
    double finalWeighted = 0.2; // assuming 100 as the score.

    return (quizWeighted + testWeighted + projWeighted + labWeighted + finalWeighted);
}

double LetterGrade(double ave){
    if(ave >= 90)
        return 'A';
    else if(ave >= 80)
        return 'B';
    else if(ave >= 70)
        return 'C';
    else if(ave >= 65)
        return 'D';
    else
        return 'F';
}

double arrayAverage(int arr[], int size){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        sum += arr[x];
    }
    return (sum / size);
}

void droppedQuizzes(int quizzes[7], int newQuizzes[5]){
    int low1 = 100, low2 = 100, count = 0;


    for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++){
        if(quizzes[x] < low2)
            if(quizzes[x] < low1)
                low1 = quizzes[x];
            else
                low2 = quizzes[x];
        else{
            newQuizzes[count] = quizzes[x];
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I get many errors, but they all say the same thing, regarding different variables:

```
Lab6.cpp:20:42: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
  droppedQuizzes(quizGrades, newQuizGrades);
                                          ^
Lab6.cpp:8:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void droppedQuizzes(int, int)’ [
 void droppedQuizzes(int, int);
      ^
```

I am aware that the * represents a pointer, but I don't understand why I can't pass an array, I've done it before in other code.

A solution would be appreciated, and an explanation more so. Thank you!

Comment: You should create a [mcve], then the problem might be obvious.

Comment: Your function prototypes at the top of the program don't match the function definitions at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The function prototypes have to specify the same signature as the function definitions. So these lines:

```
double arrayAverage(int, int);
void droppedQuizzes(int, int);
```

should be:

```
double arrayAverage(int[], int);
void droppedQuizzes(int[], int[]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Although I do have another question. I was under the impression that this only worked in Java, and that the brackets needed to be adjacent to the variable name. Is that not the case, or is something else going on here?

Comment: In prototypes the names are optional. You need the names in definitions.